# Detecting the plugins attached to an element

Tags: jquery

I want to detect all plugins associated with an element, like if the cycle plugin is associated with div whose id is cycle, then I want to access the cycle plugin.

I am doing this because in my website I am using so many plugins like cycle, fancybox, colorbox and I am providing the gallery and slideshow edit facility to user so when the user adds any image I will detect the plugin and reinitialize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you'll find a method that works for any plugin. You have to find out how to detect each plugin individually (see [How to check if a jQuery UI plugin is attached to an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679051/how-to-check-if-a-jquery-ui-plugin-is-attached-to-an-element) for an example) and write a function that performs each check.