# How to check if list is sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

How to check if a specific list is sortable? Like `$('#list').is(':sortable')`... ?

If we will use

```
if ($('#list').sortable())
```

then the list will be made sortable again and not check if actually it is sortable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find elements which have jquery widgets initialized upon them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251765/find-elements-which-have-jquery-widgets-initialized-upon-them). Just use `data("sortable")` instead of `data("fileupload")`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If the list is already sortable, then it should have class `ui-sortable`.

You could use `if ($('#list').hasClass('ui-sortable'))` to check it.

Comment: It does not work if the page is reloaded from db where html was saved with the class attached. The method suggested by jebbie is however flawless when reloading pages from db.

Answer (score 11):

I just found out, with the data-interface it is working too:

```
if ($( '#sortable' ).data( 'sortable' )) {
    // sortable instance exists
}
```

Comment: but i have to say... i believe in the newest jQuery version, this does not work anymore (i had to change all these code instances in my latest project into css-class-detection)

Comment: Checking `.data("sortable")` doesn't work, but `.data("uiSortable")` does.

Answer (score 7):

There was a change in jQuery Version after 2012, so now you can write:

```
if ($( '#sortable' ).data( 'ui-sortable' )) {
    // sortable instance exists
}
```

or

```
if ($( '#sortable' ).is(':ui-sortable')) {
    // sortable instance exists
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When applying Sorting, just add a dummy class to that element like this,

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).addClass("antguider");
```

then, If you want to check the element is sortable then check like this,

```
if($( "#sortable" ).hasClass("antguider")){
    alert("Already Sort Applied");
}
```

Comment: Why add an extra unneeded class when the sortable widget already adds the 'ui-sortable' class?

Comment: If by any chance future versions of sortable change the class name, this solution would still work.

Comment: well instead of using my own class i would rather make the class i check against configurable and if it change, i only change on config and bam, works again.. never re-invent the wheel, neat simple markup should always be the target

Answer (score 2):

I found in Safari (maybe others) the classes are not reliable. 'ui-sortable' remains on any item which has been made sortable even if you disable it, which results in the classes 'ui-sortable ui-sortable-disabled' both being used.

I found myself adding and removing the classes myself just to make sure they were as I expected.

```
if ($(this).hasClass("ui-sortable")) {
  $(this).removeClass("ui-sortable");
  $(this).sortable({ disabled: true });
}
else {
  $(this).addClass("ui-sortable");
  $(this).sortable({ disabled: false });
}
```

-- EDIT

Ok, so the classes are reliable but what I was after is not disabled but rather .sortable("destroy") which returns the element to it's state prior to initialisation (i.e removes all helper classes).

So for my sortable toggle (which is what I was creating):

```
if ($(this).hasClass("ui-sortable")) $(this).sortable("destroy");
else $(this).sortable();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57549308/4175975

Just call an instance of sortable, if return undefined, then is not loaded

```
if (typeof $("ul.sortable").sortable('instance') != 'undefined') {
    //$.ui.sortable is loaded and called
} else {
    //call sortable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
Sortable.get(element)
```

https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#sortablegetelementhtmlelementsortable

It resolves to `undefined` if no sortable instance is attached.